# Ionic app cannot load JSON file

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am learning how to use Ionic, and am currently using localhost to test the app. I am trying to build a contacts list app, and contact information such as name, email, contact phone number, and avatar are loaded from a JSON file. But nothing shows up, and the Chrome error message in the console says this: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Here is my index.html file:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane ng-controller-"myController">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
      <button class="button button-clear icon ion-navicon"></button>
        <h1 class="title">Friends List</h1>
        <button class="button button-clear icon ion-settings"></button>
      </ion-header-bar>
        <div class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
              <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
            </label>
        </div>
      <ion-content class="has-subheader">
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="element in data.persons">
            <img src="{{ element.personDisplayPicture }}"/>
            <h2>{{ element.personName }}</h2>
            <p>{{ element.personContact }}</p>
            <p>{{ element.personEmail }}</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my app.js file:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);


      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){

  $http.get('js/addressbook.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
  })

})
```

My addressbook.json file is located within the "js" folder, where my app.js file is also located. The addressbook.json file just uses some sample info like so:

```
{"persons": [
  {
    "personContact": "+91-9997725251",
    "personDisplayPicture": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/1509974_10205886752870556_6275779368926452443_n.jpg?oh=d407cc6c85c581f4ee96cd65ea15a171\u0026oe=55ECD16C\u0026__gda__=1443235524_024ba60447125011575b739fb45d23c4",
    "personEmail": "samarthagarwal@live.com",
    "personName": "Samarth Agarwal"
  },

  {
    "personContact": "+91-9874563210",
    "personDisplayPicture": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/p160x160/10997379_828487523879435_5609581450404507062_n.jpg?oh=109f958adce1bb72754ed1772e598893&oe=56276727&__gda__=1441608268_136ec1af8e25e4364909decbd724f26a",
    "personName": "Apoorva Agarwal",
    "personEmail": "apoorva@gmail.com"
  }
]}
```

Comment: try `$http.get('file:///android_asset/www/js/addressbook.json')`

Answer (score 1):

I think your code has no problem, except that angular has deprecated legacy promise methods `success` and `error` of [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) after version 1.4.4, you should use standard `then` method instead if your ionic depends on higher angular version. 
And then use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead of `src` when use url interpolation in case of url 404 error. By the way, the url of `personDisplayPicture` property in your json seems that work badly.
And for the Chrome error message, it should be an intended `cordova.js` error.
I have build a [plunker project](http://plnkr.co/edit/lIufXlUOXXgg9EtYV8z8?p=preview) that use your code. Hope this will help you, regards!

Comment: Thanks for the plunker demonstration. I tried adding in your changes, and I am no longer getting the 404 error. I am now just simply seeing nothing at all. I tried using the code to make a plunker of my own, and that worked. So it's leading me to believe that I might be using the localhost server incorrectly. I have the bar at the top, and the menu and settings icons, but no contact data is displayed.